# "Open file - security warning" on local exe: "Unblock" does *not* work - why?

Tags: windows, security, windows-explorer

I use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) on a Windows Vista (Business 32bit) box. I have extracted the files from the zip file to `C:\Program Files\Process Explorer`. Every time I open the executable (`procexp.exe`) I get the security warning that the file is not from this computer etc.

**Neither** checking the checkbox on the security warning to "not warn again" **nor** using the `[Unblock]` button in the executables properties page will remove this warning. It will always popup again, and when I re-open the properties page of procexp.exe the `[Unblock]` button will be displayed again.

**Why** can't I remove this security descriptor from this file in `C:\Program Files\...` and *what* do I have to do to remove it?

Other questions that did not help so far:

- [Remove Process Explorer's "Open File - Security Warning"](https://superuser.com/questions/166261/remove-process-explorers-open-file-security-warning)
- [Get rid of Vista security warning](https://superuser.com/questions/23613/get-rid-of-vista-security-warning)

[Questions/answer](https://superuser.com/questions/110362/shell-extension-to-unblock-downloaded-files) that *may* provide a solution (once I figure it out) ... but still the question remains as to why the `[Unblock]` button works for some but not for me?

Comment: Same problem with Windows 7 (32bit and 64bit).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I figured it out:

If you have a file that is tagged as "unsafe" and you copy this file into the `Program Files` folder, than you cannot remove the "unsafe" tagging via `[Unblock]` because you need elevation to edit the file inside `Program Files` and the Vista properties dialog does not request elevation and therefore cannot remove the "unsafe" tagging.

The solution is to move the "unsafe" executable to your documents folder, `[unblock]` it there and then move the file back to the `Program Files`folder.

Comment: This same obnoxious find is in Windows 7 as well.

Answer (score 1):

Funny enough, you can use the Sysinternals 'streams' utility to unblock them all in bulk.

Just use `streams -d *.*` from within a command prompt with administrative privileges (i.e. enter "cmd" in the Windows search box, right click cmd.exe and choose **Run as Administrator**).